# The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This problem occurred after upgrading ASP.NET MVC versions.

> The type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see that you have provided yourself an answer, but another solution is to update your web.config with a `<runtime>` element that redirects dependent assemblies and points to the correct one:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Note that updating your project from NuGet does the same thing for you automatically for most assemblies.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Actually I thought my solution had worked because I got it working locally. But when I came to bin deploy I had got stuck where one of my DLLs had somehow got a bung reference in its manifest (I am using some code I copied and pasted from MvcFutures v1 but I cannot see any versions mentioned in there). So your answer solved my secondary related problem! Thanks!

Comment: For me this indicated that, after going from MVC 3 to the NuGet version, I neglected to implement the consequentual changes in the web.config.

Answer (score 5):

In solution explorer, click on References > System.Web.Mvc. Click properties and set Copy Local = True.

This way you will be sure to get the correct version of MVC in your project and not rely on whatever version(s) are installed in the GAC. This approach also enables you to bin-deploy the MVC DLL.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the thing for me ...

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Routing" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```